# Derivative of $\frac{(x\cos\,\theta-y\sin\,\theta)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(x\sin\,\theta+y\cos\,\theta)^2}{b^2}=1$

Tags: derivatives

The derivative of 
$$\frac{(x\cos\,\theta-y\sin\,\theta)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(x\sin\,\theta+y\cos\,\theta)^2}{b^2}=1$$

is

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=-\frac{a^2 x\,\sin^2\theta+y(a-b)(a+b)\sin\,\theta \cos\,\theta+b^2 x\,\cos^2\theta}{a^2 y\,\cos^2\theta+x(a-b)(a+b)\sin\,\theta \cos\,\theta+b^2 y\,\sin^2\theta}$$

How?

Comment: is here $$y=y(x)$$?

Answer (score 1):

For brevity, let $C=\cos \theta$ and $S=\sin \theta$
\begin{align*}
  \frac{(Cx-Sy)^2}{a^2}+
  \frac{(Sx+Cy)^{2}}{b^2} &=1 \\
  \frac{2(Cx-Sy)(C-Sy')}{a^2}+
  \frac{2(Sx+Cy)(S+Cy')}{b^2} &=0 \\
  \frac{\color{red}{Cy'+S}}{\color{blue}{Sy'-C}} &=
  \frac{\color{red}{b^{2}(Cx-Sy)}}
       {\color{blue}{a^{2}(Sx+Cy)}} \\
  \frac{C\color{red}{(Cy'+S)}+S\color{blue}{(Sy'-C)}}
       {S\color{red}{(Cy'+S)}-C\color{blue}{(Sy'-C)}} &=
  \frac{C\color{red}{b^{2}(Cx-Sy)}+
        S\color{blue}{a^{2}(Sx+Cy)}}
       {S\color{red}{b^{2}(Cx-Sy)}-
        C\color{blue}{a^{2}(Sx+Cy)}} \\
  y' &=
 \frac{a^{2}S^{2}x+(a^2-b^2)SCy+b^{2}C^{2}x}
      {-a^{2}C^{2}y+(b^2-a^2)SCx-b^{2}S^{2}y}
\end{align*}

Comment: Great, btw what property has been applied at second last step?

Comment: Properties of ratio: $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} \implies \frac{\alpha a+\beta b}{\gamma a+\delta b}=\frac{\alpha c+\beta d}{\gamma c+\delta d}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the implicit function $$F=\frac{(x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta))^2}{a^2}+\frac{(x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta))^2}{b^2}-1=0$$ and compute its derivatives $$F'_x=\frac{2 \cos (\theta ) (x \cos (\theta )-y \sin (\theta ))}{a^2}+\frac{2 \cos
   (\theta ) (x \cos (\theta )+y \sin (\theta ))}{b^2}$$ $$F'_y=\frac{2 \sin (\theta ) (x \cos (\theta )+y \sin (\theta ))}{b^2}-\frac{2 \sin
   (\theta ) (x \cos (\theta )-y \sin (\theta ))}{a^2}$$Now, use the implicit function theorem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}$$ and simplify as much as you can since $$a^2b^2 F'_x=2 \cos (\theta ) \left(x \left(a^2+b^2\right) \cos (\theta )+y (a^2-b^2) \sin
   (\theta )\right)$$ $$a^2b^2 F'_y=2 \sin (\theta ) \left(x (a^2-b^2) \cos
   (\theta )+y \left(a^2+b^2\right) \sin (\theta )\right)$$